# blazy and facebook share/like

Tags: php, html, facebook, share, facebook-like

I am using a script, [blazy](http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/), to change my page's images as the user scrolls down. It works fine, and I would like the user to have the possibility to share each image to his friends on Facebook. I managed to link the url to an anchor to the image. When sharing a link, a little thumbnail is displayed with the link with a short description of the image. My problem is that only the logo of my website is displayed and not the image the user wants to share.

```
<a class="facebook_share" href="actualites.php#237" onclick="
                     window.open(
                     'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split(location.hash||'#')[0] + '#237'),
                     'facebook-share-dialog',
                     'width=626,height=436');
                     return false;">
</a>

<div id="237">
    <a href="content/posts/237/449.jpg" title="Voir en taille réelle">
       <img class="b-lazy"
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
            data-src="content/posts/237/449_thumb.png" alt="image" width="700px">
    </a>
</div>
```

Looking at [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/), I tried to create a meta tag when clicking on the Facebook share button. The result is the same -- the image I want to share is not displayed, this is because Facebook linter only looks at the HTML in the response and does not run any scripts. The content of my page always changes, I cannot write the meta tags "by hand".

```
<a class="facebook_share" href="actualites.php#237" onclick="
$('meta[name=og:image]').remove();
                      $('head').append('&lt;meta name=\'og:image\' content=\'***/content/posts/237/449_thumb.png\'&gt;');
window.open(...[see above]);
```